# Move an image to the left every time I press enter

Tags: javascript

The image moves to the left once correctly, but afterwards I press enter again it doesn't move. I'm looking for it to move left 10 more pixels everytime I press enter. Thanks

```
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13)  {

       document.getElementById("wagon").style.left=-10 + "px";
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because you just assigned -10px to the element every time you did keydown, so `left` would always be -10px. You need to extract the number from `left` and subtract 10 and do some modification.

This will do the job.

```
var leftStr = document.getElementById("wagon").style.left;
var indexOfpx = leftStr.indexOf("px");
var num = leftStr.substring(0, indexOfpx); // extract the number part
var leftPx = Number(num) - 10 + "px"; 
document.getElementById("wagon").style.left = leftPx;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, it should be

```
document.getElementById("wagon").style.left -= 10 + "px";
```

Comment: This will not work. This use of the `-=` operator expands to `….left = ….left - (10 + "px")`. But `10 + "px"` is a string. You can't subtract a string `"10px"` from a number like `0`.